# How to import python script files in folders on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm fairly new to both Python and Google App Engine.  I want to organize my script files by creating a folder structure.  However when I do that I can no longer figure out how to import them.

For example:

```
main.py
/eggs/spam.py
```

How do I import spam.py in main.py?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make eggs a package by adding an `__init__.py` file in the folder. It can be empty, as long as it's there. Then, import spam like this:

`import eggs.spam`

[More information on packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages).