# GAE/Python ImportError only on the deployed version

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment, importerror

Hi everyone I'm struggling with AppEngine, I made my webapp on the development server, everything worked fine but once I deploy it gives me an ImportError.
My main directory is as follows:

```
-/
  -Several
  -Folders
  -...
  *admin.py
  *app.yaml
  *db_objects.py
  *index.yaml
  *img_getter.py
  *keys.py
  *main.py
  *main_handler.py
```

My app.yaml file:

```
application: myapplication (this is not the real name)
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

default_expiration: "7d"

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /admin.*
  script: admin.app
  login: admin

- url: /checkout.*
  script: main.app
  login: required

- url: /confirm.*
  script: main.app
  login: required

- url: /changeinfo.*
  script: main.app
  login: required

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

When I go to myaddress.appengine.com/admin it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
   handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapplication/1.383371027775991819/admin.py", line 7, in <module>
  import img_getter
ImportError: No module named img_getter
```

This is the beginning of admin.py:

```
#coding=utf-8

import webapp2
from main_handler import Handler
import db_objects
from google.appengine.ext import db
import img_getter
from google.appengine.api import memcache
import keys

from datetime import date

class MainHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect("/admin/noticias")
...
```

And this is the beginning of the img_getter.py file:

```
import gdata.photos.service
import gdata.media
import gdata.geo

def foo(variable):
    ...

def bar(variable):
    ...
#functions to get images from the google picassa service
```

The thing is I've been developing this webapp on the developer server and it's been working like a charm, I've even cleared the datastore and tried on several computers and it's still working, but when I try to test it on Google servers I'm finding this error.

I haven't define any reference on the app.yaml file as I think it's not necesary because it's not a library depending from google python API, am I wrong?
Does anybody know what the problem is?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to import it as a package.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

1. Create a folder called 'test' (or whatever you want) for img_getter.py and put it in there
2. Add a file called `__init__.py` and save it in the folder you put img getting in.  This file can be empty
3. call the import as
   import test.img_getter

Reference 
[How to import python script files in folders on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517625/how-to-import-python-script-files-in-folders-on-google-app-engine)

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. I've been working with python and appengine for a few months now and I didn't know about that. Thanks again : )

Comment: My pleasure.  That one tripped me up when I was starting out too.  Cheers!